# Pandas not merging all rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to merge two dataframes with pandas. When I look at the data there should be two output rows, but I am only getting one row.

```
bankDF = bankDF[bankDF['transaction detail'].str.contains("RSA")]
bankDF['bank index'] = bankDF['bank index'].map(str)
bankDF = bankDF.groupby(['post date']).agg({'amount': 'sum', 'bank index': ','.join}).reset_index()
bankDF['amount type'] = bankDF['amount'].dtypes

glDF = glDF[glDF['ref3'].str.contains("RSA", na=False)]

matchedGL = pd.merge(bankDF, glDF, on='amount', suffixes=("_left", "_right"))
```

bankDF is:

```
 post date     amount       amount type
 2022-05-04   -410372.62     float64
 2022-05-26   -407418.78     float64
```

glDF is:

```
journal   eff date    amount      amount type
81132.0   2022-05-31  -407418.78   float64
81132.0   2022-05-31  -417118.28   float64
81592.0   2022-05-31  -410372.62   float64
```

And my output is:

```
post date   amount      amount type_left  journal   eff date    amount type_right
2022-05-26  -407418.78   float64          81132.0   2022-05-31  float64
```

My expectation would be that both the rows from bankDF would match the two rows on glDF. What am I missing that would cause the -410372.62 amount not match?

Comment: It's likely that the value isn't actually `-410372.62` in one or both frames, but rather a larger decimal.

Comment: You can try converting float to string for this merge and see if that solves the issues

Comment: Thank you both! Converting to a string revealed that the value was actually -410372.6200005. Dealing with the decimals at the groupby and sum location cleared up the issue!